# Python winreg not printing

Tags: python, winreg

Hi there im trying to understand this code. I know it gets the gateway name and mac address in registry but when i tried to run this code, it doesn't show anything. Can someone give me links about winreg that has basic examples. Thank You

```
from winreg import *
def val2addr(val):
    addr = ''
    for ch in val:
        addr += '%02x '% ord(ch)
    addr = addr.strip(' ').replace(' ', ':')[0:17]
    return addr

def printNets():
    net = r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows     NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged"
    key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, net)
    print ("[*] Networks You have Joined.")
    for i in range(100):
        try:
            guid = EnumKey(key, i)
            netKey = OpenKey(key, str(guid))
            (n, addr, t) = EnumValue(netKey, 5)
            (n, name, t) = EnumValue(netKey, 4)
            macAddr = val2addr(addr)
            netName = str(name)
            print ('[+] ' + netName + ' ' + macAddr)
            CloseKey(netKey)
        except:
            break

def main():
    printNets()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: how are you running this?

Comment: using sublime text editor with python 3.3

Answer (score 0):

1. Module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html).  Read it to understand function args/returns.
2. [Example](http://effbot.org/librarybook/winreg.htm) showing registry key values/current user information.
3. A very thorough [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498150-example-for-winreg-1/) showing many, many things winreg can do.